# I have a site in asp.net mvc4 and want to include a module in nancy fx,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nancy

I have a site in asp.net mvc4 and want to include a module in nancy fx, I follow the instructions of https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-asp.net not work but I did not the Hello World !. someone can help me with some content.

when I disable RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes) in Global.asax.cs, my nancy model works but not my MVC site, and when I enable RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes); working my mvc site but not my nancy model.

Comment: How did it fail for you? Can you show your code?

Comment: when I disable RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes) in Global.asax.cs, my nancy model works but not my MVC site, and when I enable RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes); working my mvc site but not my nancy model.

Comment: could be that you have a greedy route in the route table that shadows the Nancy module. IOW MVC handles all requests before Nancy gets a chance.